# My hearthstone installation is stuck "waiting on another installation"

Tags: hearthstone, battle.net

My Hearthstone is stuck and will not start. I tried deleting all the caches and it had no affect. This is what it looks like:

[image: hearthstone stuck]

Comment: This happened to be but for Overwatch when Blizzard had those DDoS attacks a couple weeks ago. Not sure if this is related, but worth a check

Comment: You should have shown the entire window in your screenshot. You'll see in the left another game or client updating

Comment: Just to clarify: nothing else was updating. This was the state of the screen for hours, so it is not a download issue.

Comment: This happened to me yesterday as well but with Diablo III.  Hearthstone was also waiting for an update but I gave D3 priority.  It was stuck but resolved itself after a restart.

Answer (score 6):

Battle.net updates or installs one game at a time. If you're trying to play Hearthstone while another game is updating you'll have to wait for that update or force the launcher to prefer Hearthstone instead.

**You can enforce the Hearthstone update by clicking the arrow/triangle button on the right side of the loading bar.**  By doing so the launcher pauses the other game update and starts with Hearthstone right away.

Once Hearthstone has been checked (and updated, if necessary) you can play it. The launcher will then continue updating the other games in the background, if you enabled it. Otherwise it will continue when you have finished playing. No harm will be done either way.

Comment: One little clarification, the battle.net client updating also blocks games from updating. Also it's harder to notice.

Comment: Like @Aequitas said the battle.net client updating also blocks, but clicking the button to launch the game update doesn't work then.

Comment: You shouldn't see that button when battle.net is being updated. But yes, critical bnet updates block games from being launched as well.

Comment: This did not work.

Comment: So it was stuck on another installation. Restarting the app usually fixes that. It's hard to see with the games list being cut off.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell it from the screenshot (it is not the whole window I guess), but all game downloads and installations are paused while the client is updating. For the clients downloading and installation status, click the battle.net logo on the top left corner.